# python setup.py create empty directory on installation

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, directory, setup.py

I'm trying to create an empty directory when distributing my python package on Ubuntu machines.

What I did so far is to add the following line to setup object under `setup.py`:

```
data_files=[('opt/my_project', [])
```

Which is not working. I thought it's because there are no files in it so I tried this:

```
data_files=[('opt/my_project', ['empty.txt'])
```

Unfortunately nothing happens in `opt` directory during installation. Also - there are no error messages.

What is the proper way to create an empty directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a "/" at the beginning of your path...

Comment: LOL! can't believe it just happened to me.. :)